how to have vpn traffic routed to pihole
i have a pihole server running in docker compose on my Debian Linux server. i also host a wireguard vpn (also in docker compose) running on the same server. by using the tcpdump command i have confirmed that all traffic that happens on my laptop is routed to the Debian server. my only issue at this stage is pihole ad blocking doesn't seem to work while using it which is really important to me in some circumstances. is there anyway to have my wireguard vpn traffic use my pihole dns server?
